# How to remove the parameters in url Java

Tags: java, string, url, uri

I have a URL when I run my project.

http://localhost:8084/blog1_1/title?uname=55%22

and I want remove the query string from this URL like below:

http://localhost:8084/blog1_1/title

Can you please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: `String sub = urlString.substring(0, urlString.indexOf('?'))`

Comment: The url is the bit you wish to remove. The parameters are the values after the '?'.

Comment: This is a good, useful question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String url="http://localhost:8084/blog1_1/title?uname=55%22";
String onlyUrl=url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("?")); //this has the URL
```

Comment: thnx bro but can you please tell me where I have to put this code ??

Comment: put it where you need .. get the whole URL into a variable and then extract it like above ..Do you need to do it server-side or client-side? @MehandiHassan

Comment: now i got the url but how to set the url in browser?

Comment: @MehandiHassan you have to make an another request for this page using `sendRedirect(url)` method

Comment: Bro i got u.
but I have an issue with my page how get i url dynamically and set the url in browser.

Comment: If you want to set the URL in browser use scripting for that .. what I told you is server-side code..

Comment: Why do you use lastIndexOf() instead of indexOf()?

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt Wouldn't that need to be escaped anyway?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the `url` is a java String:

```
String newURL = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
```

should do the trick...

Comment: in the place where you want to use this url, e.g. pass it as a parameter to a method(?)

Comment: how to get the url and how to set the url in browser

Comment: please, post this as a new question

Answer (score 0):

Java:

```
String newURL = Uri.parse("YOUR_URL").getPath()
```

Kotlin:

```
val newURL = Uri.parse("YOUR_URL").path
```

Comment: this will return only last path of url

Answer (score 0):

If you have your URL as an object and not a String you can do this:

Kotlin:

```
val url = URL("http://localhost:8084/blog1_1/title?uname=55%22")

val host = url.host
val path = url.path

val newUrl = URL("https://$host$path")
```

Java:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/blog1_1/title?uname=55%22");
    
String host = url.getHost();
String path = url.getPath();

URL newUrl = new URL("https://" + host + path);
```