# fetch the url from the browser java web and replace the url with new url

Tags: java, jsp, url-rewriting

I have a url when running a project and I want to get the url from browser and replace the new url dynamically.

Example we are having a url as below:-

> http://localhost:8084/blog1_1/title?uname=55%22

replace it with the url

> http://localhost:8084/blog1_1/title

and set this url in browser ???

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917970/how-to-remove-the-parameters-in-url-java

Answer (score 0):

Just do the redirect to your desired URL:

```
response.sendRedirect("/blog1_1/title");
```